TinyMCE Offering Variations of Headings
Can anyone offer any solution to how to offer alternatives to Heading 1,2,3 in the TinyMCE blocks plugin?
By default TinyMCE offers Heading 1-6 and Paragraph tag but I'd like to offer my users the ability to use a standard Heading 1 OR a Heading 1 that has slightly different styling.
I know the answer is somewhere in the style_formats or formats option but I can't for the life of me work it out.
Anyone know how to do it?
Cheers
